# OpenStreetMap freeway signs

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

I am looking for a dataset that includes freeway exit and ramp signs used for navigational purposes.  Signs such as "Exit 25, Campbell Avenue" or a sign indicating to keep right to merge onto a different freeway.  Does this data exist in an open source format?  If it is compatible with OSM data that would be amazing, but I can process it if not.  I know mapquest, google, etc have it because they include that sort of info in their routing, but I'm not sure if it is available to the public anywhere.

Comment: In what country are you looking at ?